# Unpack Dictionaries for Logistic Regression in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, logistic-regression, sentiment-analysis

I'm trying to run some sentiment analysis on product reviews, and I'm getting tripped up with getting my model to read the word count dictionaries

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np   
from sklearn import linear_model, model_selection, metrics

products = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

def count_words(s):
   d = {}
   wl = str(s).split()
   for w in wl:
       d[w] = wl.count(w)
   return d

products['word_count'] = products['review'].apply(count_words)

products = products[products['rating'] != 3]
products['sentiment'] = (products['rating'] >= 4) * 1 

train_data, test_data = model_selection.train_test_split(products, test_size = 0.2, random_state=0)

sentiment_model = linear_model.LogisticRegression()
sentiment_model.fit(X = train_data['word_count'], y =train_data['sentiment'])
```

When I run that last line I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-0c3f47af3a6e> in <module>()
----> 1 sentiment_model.fit(X = train_data['word_count'], y = 
train_data['sentiment'])

C:\ProgramData\anaconda_3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\logistic.py 
in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
   1171 
   1172         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse='csr', dtype=np.float64,
-> 1173                          order="C")
   1174         check_classification_targets(y)
   1175         self.classes_ = np.unique(y)

C:\ProgramData\anaconda_3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in 
check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    519     X = check_array(X, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite,
    520                     ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples,
--> 521                     ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    522     if multi_output:
    523         y = check_array(y, 'csr', force_all_finite=True, ensure_2d=False,

C:\ProgramData\anaconda_3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    380                                       force_all_finite)
    381     else:
--> 382         array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
    383 
    384         if ensure_2d:

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict'
```

It seems like the model is pulling the dictionaries as the x variables instead of the entries in the dictionaries. I think I need to unpack the dictionaries into arrays (?) but haven't had any luck doing so.

update:
Here is that products looks like after running word_count and defining sentiment
[products.head()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwPbn.jpg)

Comment: Can you provide a minimal sample of `data.csv`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just correct the error, first use [DictVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer) on the `train_data['word_count']` to convert it into acceptable format which is an array of shape `[n_samples, n_features]`.

Add the below to your code before `sentiment_model.fit()`:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
dictVectorizer = DictVectorizer()

train_data_dict = dictVectorizer.fit_transform(train_data['word_count'])
```

Then call sentiment_model.fit() like this:

```
sentiment_model.fit(X = train_data_dict, y =train_data['sentiment'])
```

**Note**:-
And instead of implementing your own count words method, I would recommend you to use [CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html).

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

countVec = CountVectorizer()

train_data_vectorizer = countVec.fit_transform(train_data['review'])
sentiment_model.fit(X = train_data_vectorizer, y =train_data['sentiment'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
X = train_data['word_count'].values()
```

This should return a list of word counts (numbers) for each item in `train_data['word_count']` if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: I got: TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Comment: Use `.values` with no call

Comment: Tried .values and it went back to:   TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict'

Comment: OK then try `print train_data['word_count']` right before you train the model, and `type(train_data['word_count'])`. What does it give you, can you reproduce a sample here? EDIT for Py 3, you need parentheses around the `print` stmt.